# ChromeDriver "failed to start" when Selenium started via Jenkins (Mac OS X)

Tags: php, macos, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Config: Mac OS X 10.8.5, java 1.6.0_65, Selenium 2.37, Jenkins 1.538, Chrome 30.0.1599.101, ChromeDriver v2.6.232908 and Firefox 25.0.
I'm running tests using PHPUnit 3.7.28 and PHP 5.3.22 (using PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase).

(1) If I manually start Selenium like so:

```
 $ java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

I can run tests as expected.

(2) However, if I start Selenium via Jenkins:

```
 # launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

And then run my tests, I get an error:

```
$ phpunit --verbose tests/classes/core/admin_campaignhome_loads.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 20.56 seconds, Memory: 5.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) AdminTest::testLoginToBackend
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232908,platform=Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.53 seconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'Pauls-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

/usr/local/php5-20130308-201415/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
/usr/local/php5-20130308-201415/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
/usr/local/php5-20130308-201415/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

(3) Firefox + Selenium via Jenkins lets me run tests as expected.

jenkins.log has the following:

```
14:51:11.439 INFO - Executing: [new session: {browserName=chrome}] at URL: /session)
14:51:11.440 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.6.232908) on port 33014
14:51:31.972 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'Pauls-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpRemoteConfig.handleRequest(JsonHttpRemoteConfig.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:167)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:139)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:677)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:568)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:914)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'Pauls-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructor(DefaultDriverFactory.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructor(DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232908,platform=Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.53 seconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'Pauls-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:129)
    ... 14 more
14:51:31.974 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232908,platform=Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.53 seconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'Pauls-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the jenkins started instance doesn't have the chrome capability

Look at

```
http://localhost:4444
```

to see the capabilities it has

You can add additional capabilities in with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -role node \
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register  \
    -browser "browserName=chrome,version=25,maxInstances=5" \
    -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver" \ 
    -host localhost \
    -port 5556
```

You can use different `-port` settings to spin up several capabilites from the same machine or even connect in from different machines by changing the `-hub` to the real address of the selenium server

---

EDIT

I recreated your problem with connecting my chrome driver without the

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver='...'
```

I'm on v2.33.0

> 13:18:44.922 WARN - Exception thrown
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
>   '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38' System
>   info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '3.2.0-55-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_45' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:176)

So I suspect the Selenium-jenkins plugin you're using has no chromedriver set or it has an invalid one.
There is a log to check (I don't have the selenium grid on my Jenkins anymore) or possibly add the path to the chromedriver to your path as in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/-3LJ3wma3RE

Comment: 1. If I look at http://localhost:8080/selenium/ before running your I already see Chrome listed (`http://192.168.1.18:4445 {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=MAC, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, jenkins.nodeName=(master)} Idle`).

If I run your command, I see a second set of instances (`http://localhost:5556 {platform=MAC, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, version=30}`).

Why's that?

2. Is there a way to have Jenkins start the Selenium instance with Chrome support? It seems odd to have to add the node each time.

Comment: I updated my answer but I think that jenkins cant find the chromedriver file

Comment: chromedriver is in /usr/bin. I also manually set the ChromeDriver path in the [Jenkins/Selenium config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjgwlqh6iwjbiql/selenium-config.png).

Comment: Not sure how much it's correct to specify chromedriver path as global Jenkins variable -- this should better be in build agent.